Movie title? Guy tired with his life goes on a journey
I only remember seeing trailer of this movie looong time ago, so my memories may be a little hazy.
A guy (most likely a journalist), gets tired with his life and work. One day he gets an offer to travel somewhere far away, but declines. But then he snaps (after getting a phonecall I guess?) and jumps into a helicopter that's already taking off.
I was sure that the main role was played by Steve Carell, but none of his movies on imdb seem to fit it.

How 'looong', exactly? ;) What was the genre?

Steve Carell, Ben Stiller, who can tell the difference. You described the trailer for the 2013 film The Secret Life of Walter Mitty. Very Drab life, how it implies he's a photo journalist (he's not), the helicopter already in mid takeoff.




That's exactly it! I can't believe how wrongly I remembered it and how you could still guess it despite that. Thank you so much!

@carrien he works with/the plot revolves around finding the photo journalist, his life is very boring, and Carell/Stiller have a very similar style of comedy and generic white everyman look. You were only wrong about finer details, but a pretty good match for the trailer :)
